# a gamma integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function

any idea how to do this integral ?

$$\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}\frac{\Gamma(3+it)}{\Gamma(3+it-j)}e^{ikt}dt$$

$j$ is a positive integer. $k$ is a constant - not necessarily positive -

Comment: Where does it comes from and what have you tried?

Comment: Landau's theorem on the coefficients of a Dirichlet series. and i've tried integration by parts . no luck though .

Comment: With $T\to\infty$, it looks like a Fourier Transform... (this is not meant as a hint, just an observation). You mean the [Landau prime ideal theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_prime_ideal_theorem)? and finally: interesting +1.

Comment: And Landau didn't know how to evaluate it?  So you expect that we do?

Comment: no ... i can't find a wiki entry. the theory basically gives a way to calculate the coefficients of a Dirichlet series . i thought of the Fourier transform, but it doesn't make things any easier.

Comment: @GEdgar .. it's a specific application of landau's theorem. i.e: a specific Dirichlet series

Comment: The quotient of gammas is a polynomial of degree $j$, so when $k=0$ your limit usually is infinite.

Comment: @MohammadAlJamal: perhaps if you find any answers to your previous questions satisfactory, you'd consider selecting one as an "accepted answer" by ticking the checkmark on the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $j=1$ apply the identity $\Gamma(z-1)=\Gamma(z)/(z-1)$ with $z=3+it$ to the denominator to rewrite the problem as
$$ \frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}(2+it)e^{ikt}\,dt = \frac{\cos(kT)}{k} + \frac{(2k-1)\sin(kT)}{k^2T} $$ using integration by parts. This diverges as $T\to\infty$. The expression diverges for larger values of $j$ also --- when $j=2$ for example, the integrand has a quadratic in $t$.